# Applying the residue theorem to $\log^2(|1+hz|)$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have to calculate an integral of the following form:$$\oint_{|z|=1} \log^2\left(\frac{|1+hz|^2}{(1-y2)^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-r^{-1}}\right)\,\mathrm dz,$$
where $h,r$ and $y2$ are constants with $0<h,y2<1<r$. 
Ideally I'd like to use the Cauchy Residue theorem however the log term is not holomorphic due to the modulus function.

Using the fact that $|1+hz|^2 = (1+hz)(1+h\bar{z})$ we can expand the square logarithm as follows:
$$\small\oint_{|z|=1} \left[\log^2\left(\frac{1+hz}{(1-y2)^2}\right) + 
2\log\left(\frac{1+hz}{(1-y2)^2}\right)\log\left(\frac{1+h\bar{z}}{(1-y2)^2}\right) + \log^2\left(\frac{1+h\bar{z}}{(1-y2)^2}\right)\right]\left(\frac{1}{z-r^{-1}}\right)\,\mathrm dz.$$
This is useful since we can use the Residue theorem to calculate the integral of the $\log^2$ terms.
However I'm still left with the product of logs which I have no idea how to integrate.
Does anyone know I can integrate the $\log \log$ term?

This is related to the limiting expectation and variance of an eigenvalue statistic, and a solution does exist.

Comment: Whate is $y2$? Is it $(\Im z)^2$?

Comment: Apologies, $y2<1$ is a constant. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Do you have a reason to suppose a solution exists?

Comment: It's related to the limiting expectation and variance of an eigenvalue statistic. A solution does exist. The variance and expectation have been worked out in the log case so it's possible to calculate an exact expression for the $log^2$ case which is a function of the above integral.